# What is the point of new confirm admin email process?

Tags: wp-admin, core, email-verification

I just noticed this, in 4.9.1 don't know when it started but not in 3.9. When I went to change my admin email, I saw this:

[image]

It used to be:
[image]

Can someone point me to the changelog for this? This seems like a really bad idea to me. First of all, who is the "we" who is going to email me? These are self hosted sites. When you change the admin email now, it won't actually change until a confirmation email is clicked, **SENT FROM THE OLD EMAIL ON SELF HOSTED SITES.** It seems you can't change the admin email unless you have database access. Thoughts?

---

UPDATE

---

Since this question was posted I published a plugin in the .org repo to resolve this issue.

[Change Admin Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/)

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39118

Comment: "We" is the server that hosts your install. You don't need database access to make this change, you only need access to whatever the new email address is.

Comment: Milo, what if you don't have access to the OLD email. Your site is bricked? That's an external feature to WordPress, and could change for reasons that have nothing to do with your WordPress install. For instance if you used an external email service. It's very easy to setup WordPress, it's incredibly difficult for most people to setup an email server.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this was downvoted?

Comment: again, you only need access to the new email account, the old email account is not involved in the change.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [announcement post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/10/13/account-security-improvements-in-wordpress-4-9/):

> A few account security enhancements have gone into WordPress 4.9. The
>   intention is to make it more difficult for an attacker to take over a
>   user account or a site by changing the email address associated with
>   the user or the site, and also to reduce the chance of a mistaken or
>   erroneous change causing you to get locked out.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I'll accept once I get some points on this new account. The reason I noticed this is because I was changing my email, and I deleted the old email I was using. Now I can't access the site [well, I can because I have SSH access, but this is a serious issue to non technical admins]. I think this is a dubious "improvement". If you can login as an admin, you shouldn't need to also have PREVIOUSLY setup email in order to change it. It's a very different situation in a single site vs multi.

Comment: Another issue is, to my knowledge, now the absolute only setting you can't change from a localhost machine if your WordPress install isn't connected to the internet. You can install plugins, and change arbitrary code, but you can't change the admin email setting?

Comment: Final issue is the "we" that appears here. Who is "we"? If I setup a WordPress site, and I haven't setup the email, now I'm faced with this "we" thing. It's the only instance of any menu addressing the user from the plural first person "we". It doesn't say "we will activate a plugin" when you activate a plugin. When I first saw this, my jaw dropped, because I thought either the Foundation or Automatic was somehow collecting emails from my sight. Bad idea.

Comment: I suggest [creating a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket) if you want to suggest an improvement. Regarding "we", I believe this is a holdover from the setting on Multisite, where "we" would refer to the network owners/superadmin.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn´t work for me. Also tried with a SMTP-plugin. Don´t get any email to the correct email I want to use as admin email. It worked to send as a test to a @gmail-address! Had the same problems on 3 other sites also.

Changed it directly in the db instead.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/